# Unreal Engine For Loop Max Iteration

Tags: unreal-engine4

we have to generate sandbox world. When we creating world, we are using too many for loops and unreal engine's max iteration for for loop is 1million. We are using for loop at first generation of map and we also use for loop for soil types, sea, tree etc. For this max iteraion number (unreal engine max iteration 1million) is not enought our generating algorithm.

Can you give us advice about map generation on game engines without too many for loop or is there any source about world generation algorithm ?

Comment: If you're running a blueprint loop for over 1 million iterations, you should not be doing it in blueprints.

Answer (score 1):

When trapped in max loop iteration , when you reach the last index re-run the loop from start with an offset.

You can also try changing this variable:
Edit>Project Settings>General Settings>Blueprints>Maximum Loop Iteration Count.